# mean of c(NA, NA) differs between na.rm = TRUE and na.rm = FALSE why?

Tags: r, nan, na

What is the explanation for this behavior?

```
> mean(c(NA,NA), na.rm = TRUE)
[1] NaN
> mean(c(NA,NA), na.rm = FALSE)
[1] NA
```

Comment: Because in the first case you are removing `NA`s, so dividing by zero elements, which is `NaN`.  In the second, you are just averaging two `NA`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mean(c(NA,NA), na.rm = TRUE)
```

For this function, NA is removed, and there will be no element left in the vector. Hence, the way R calculate will be 0/0 => NaN

```
mean(c(NA,NA), na.rm = FALSE)
```

For this function, NA is not removed, and the mean function will be applied to the vector c(NA,NA). Hence, it will be (NA + NA)/2 => NA

Comment: Isn't this just repeating what Andrew Gustar and I said in the comments an hour beforehand?

Comment: Absolutely, however, it didn't hurt anyone to accept the answer. Well, probably the one person who down voted the question. I can live with that.